# Optimization-Setting textview's style using BindingAdapter

Tags: android, optimization, android-styles, android-databinding

I want to set style of `TextView` based on certain condition and I am using data binding in my project. I am able to do that using `BindingAdapter`.

```
public final class BindingAdapters {

    @BindingAdapter({"bindStyle"})
    public static void setFontStyle(TextView textView, String typefaceName) {
        textView.setTextAppearance(context, typefaceName.equals(context.getResources().getString(R.string.string1)) ? R.style.style1 : R.style.style2);}
}
```

xml

```
app:bindStyle="@{val ==xyz ? @string/string1: @string/string2}"
```

Here I declared two strings in strings.xml and passing one of those string to `setFontStyle` method based on condition and based on the string passed i am deciding which style to set.

But I wonder is there any better way of doing that? Is there any way that i can directly pass style to `setFontStyle` method  and set it to `TextView` so that method can be used for entire project. Or any other better way of setting style using data binding?

Answer (score 0):

> You can create the binding adapter like below.

```
 @BindingAdapter({"bindStyle"})
        public static void setFontStyle(TextView textView, String text) {
            if (text.equals("value"))
                textView.setTextAppearance(textView.getContext(), R.style.SettingHeading);
            else
                textView.setTextAppearance(textView.getContext(), R.style.SettingText);
        }
```

> XML

```
         <data>
            <variable
                name="val"
                type="String" />
        </data>

     app:bindStyle="@{val}"
```

Why you need to check the condition twice to apply the style.You can put your logic in the binding adapter itself and apply the style accordingly.